# Testing in Django Rest Framework, reproduce this curl request?

Tags: python, django, curl, django-rest-framework

I am trying to run some testing for [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing) (links to testing) and reproduce this curl call:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>"
http://<client_id>:<client_secret>@127.0.0.1:8000/v1/token/
```

This is what I have tried:

```
  def test_oauth2_token_for_user(self):
        """
        Test Django OAuth Toolkit and make a request for am access token.
        """
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='grant_type ' + "password&username=<user_name>&password=<password")
        response = self.client.post('/api/token/')
```

Could someone tell me where to start. I am unsure how to send the header `grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>` and format the URL with the username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a header. That's perfectly normal POST data, which - as the [test client documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) shows - you can just pass in a dictionary as the second parameter to `post`.

```
response = self.client.post('/api/token/',
       {'grant_type': 'password', 'username': username, 'password': password})
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to post to this api sending the post data and the authorization data with django's test Client.

My solution was set a test with LiveServerTestCase(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) and post using the requests library:

```
 class AuthTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def test_auth(self):
        # ...
        requests.post(
            http://localhost:8082/o/token/,
            dict(username="myuser",
                 password="mypass",
                 grant_type="password"
                 ),
            auth=(MYAPP.client_id, MYAPP.client_secret)
        )
```